# Is it unsafe to have hashes of parts of a private string

Tags: hash, password-cracking

We have string *B* and the hashes `hash(P+B)`, `hash(P)`;   is it possible for *P* to be revealed easier using this information than having `hash(P)` ?  What is the difference ?
Any links to articles or any kind of information to help me better understand this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extra information can only help the attacker; but that extra help might be negligible.

If we model the hash function as a [random oracle](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/879/what-is-the-random-oracle-model-and-why-is-it-controversial/880#880), then showing *h*(*P*+*B*) for a given non-empty string *B* does *not* yield extra information useful for the attacker (I take "+" to mean here string concatenation, not numerical addition). A "random oracle" is (in rough terms) a function such that you know nothing on its output for any given input without trying it. When you have *h*(*x*), you can gain information on *x* only through brute force, i.e. trying out potential values for *x* until a match is found. Thus, *h*(*P*+*B*) does not give any extra power to the attacker, compared to *h*(*P*), and regardless how *B* was chosen: the attacker still has to try potential *P* values and hope to get lucky. The best that the attacker can do to optimize things on his side is to choose a strategy that minimizes the computational cost of each try; since common hash functions have a cost that is proportional to the input size, the attacker will prefer to work with *h*(*P*) than *h*(*P*+*B*) anyway.

The trouble with the random oracle model is that usual hash functions are *not* random oracles. However, in the case of [Merkle–Damgård](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) hash functions (a category that includes common hash functions such as MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256 and SHA-512), there is a property called "[length extension attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack)": given *h*(*P*), it is possible to compute *h*(*P*+*B*) for *B* values that can be, to a large extent, chosen at will, and you can do that without knowing *P* (you need to know the *length* of *P*, but not its actual value). The length extension attack is usually accounted for as either an harmless curiosity, or a weakness (in most protocols, it is harmless and can be ignored); but, in our case, it has an interesting consequence. Namely, it allows us to show that revealing *h*(*P*+*B*) does not give extra information to the attacker, precisely because the attacker did not need wait for us: he could *already* compute *h*(*P*+*B*) for a large class of *B* values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm slightly confused by the construction of your question, but should still be able to shed some light on the subject in any case.

First, I'm going to assume that when you say `P+B` you intended to mean that `P` and `B` are going to be concatenated, rather than that addition in some form is being preformed, and I'll denoted this below with the `||` notation rather than `+`.

Second, the output of a cryptographically secure hash function does not reveal any information about its input.  If it did, it would cease to be considered a secure function.  So, merely knowing `H(P||B)` is, in fact, the hash of two unknown inputs, (P and B) and `H(P)` is also the hash of one of those unknowns doesn't give you any information about what the unknown inputs actually are.

Third, a cryptographically secure hash function will produce outputs that are indistinguishable from random for efficient tests.  This means that related inputs (in this case the `P` is the related part of the input) are not going to produce related outputs.  Given `H(P||B)` without knowing that it is in fact a hash of `P` and `B` will produce an output that is unrelated to the output of `H(P)`.  You will not learn anything about `P` or `B` from `H(P)` or about `P` from `H(P||B)`.

So, what can be attacked?  Because you don't learn anything about the inputs from the output of a cryptographically secure hash function, the way that you attack it is by testing candidate inputs and comparing them to the given hash output to see if the match, generally using either a dictionary or brute force to generate the input candidates.   Given this, the shorter and less random the input, the fewer input candidates need to be tested in order find a match.  Therefore, the obvious approach an attacker would take assuming he knows that the hashes are the result of `H(P||B)` and `H(P)` and knows which is which, but doesn't know either `P` or `B` would be to attack the output of `H(P)`.  Because the input is smaller, and the bits of entropy is necessarily less (`B` must add at least one bit of entropy to the input by virtue of existing) an attacker will be able to find `P` more quickly than `P||B`, and then use that to attack `H(P||B)` to try to find `B`.

That is not, however, to say that finding `P` from `H(P)` is necessarily easy, or even realistically possible, however.  It's only theoretically easier.  It *may* be possible, and even easy, but that depends entirely on the properties of `P`.  If it is small, and non-random, for some values of small and non-random, it's completely doable.  If it is large and quite random, the number of candidate tests required may make it infeasible to compute the required number of hash values in order to find the correct input.